# Parse json array with out object in python

Tags: python

I have a below json array file with out object. How do I parse it in python. I would like to construct all dataNomTime into a array.

```
[{
    "id": 8916,
    "objectPaths": ["/thmo/help"],
    "dataTime": 1464961203,
    "dataNomTime": 1464818400,
    "dataEndTime": 1464904800,
    "attribs": null
}, {
    "id": 8917,
    "objectPaths": ["/thmo/help"],
    "dataTime": 1464961203,
    "dataNomTime": 1464818400,
    "dataEndTime": 1464904800,
    "attribs": null
}]
```

My code

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

#pprint(data)
pprint(data["dataNomTime"])
```

Exception

```
 pprint(data["dataNomTime"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a list of dictionaries, `data` is a list and should be treating as a list.

If you want to extract all the `dataNomTime` you should do:

```
nom_times_list = []
for obj in data:
    nom_times_list.append(obj['dataNomTime'])
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
nom_times_list = [obj['dataNomTime'] for obj in data]
```

Comment: what is the differene betwwen list comprehension and append ?